# PWA: Disable or detect the black bottom bar on iOS

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, progressive-web-apps

Is there an easy way to disable this black bottom bar on iOS devices (with CSS for instance) or detect it with JavaScript? (For progressive web apps)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`env(safe-area-inset-bottom, 20px)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env()) in CSS to avoid the overlap as described in [Designing Websites for iPhone X](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/).

Comment: Note that you'll need `viewport-fit=cover` in your "viewport" meta tag for this to kick in

Comment: Don't forget, that this makes the page in landscape quite unusable because some page content is obscured by the device’s sensor housing.